Carga de Tailwind css en proyecto Vite con Vue +TS
Estoy tratando de cargar Tailwind en un proyecto de Vite con Vue JS y Typescript.
He seguido la creación del proyecto segundo la documentación oficial de Vite, creando el proyecto con el siguiente comando:
npm create vite@latest

Cuando tengo ya el proyecto corriendo, sigo las instrucciones de la documentación oficial de Tailwind: Documentación de Tailwind: Instalación en Vite
modificando el punto 4 ya que en el ejemplo se aplica un código de React de modo que se me queda el componente creado del siguiente modo:


<script setup lang="ts">


</script>

<template>
  <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>



Finalmente, esto se visualiza sin ningún tipo de estilo aplicado:

Decir también que he probado con un proyecto en React con Vite y no ha habido problema alguno con Tailwind css.
Muchas gracias.

Notaste que en esa misma página hay una guía para React, otra para Vue y otra para Svelte? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue en el paso 4 difiere en el archivo que hay que modificar

Buenas tardes Mateo. Efectivamente me avergüenza confirmarte que no me había dado cuenta de que hay otra pestaña para vue y el fallo lo tenia en el paso 3. Ya funciona todo correctamente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Al menos ya encontraste la solución. Solo faltaba modificar el archivo css correcto, no? Puedes agregarlo como respuesta a tu pregunta así más gente podrá encontrar la solución

Buenos días Mateo. El archivo css lo tenia correctamente modificado, ya que por descarte modifiqué el archivo correcto en su momento. El fallo venia en el punto 3, en el que se hace referencia a los archivos con extensión vue para aplicar los estilos del css, y que no viene en el fragmento perteneciente a React. Agrego esto como respuesta por si a alguien mas le sucede. Muchas gracias.

Para los que se encuentren con el mismo problema que yo, la documentación de Tailwind CSS, referente a la instalación en Vite, esta divido por pestañas en base al framework Javascript que se va a usar. Aunque parezcan similares los fragmentos de código no son exactamente iguales (difieren en los puntos 3 y 4)


